# Why can't I populate appended select in php?

Tags: php, html, jquery

**clientAdd.php**

```
 <?php 

                    $office = "SELECT * FROM tblOffice";
                    $office_qry = mysqli_query($conn, $office);

                    ?>

                       <div class="input-field"> 
                        <label> Office </label>
                    <select id="office-dd" name="office-dd">
                    <option disabled selected value>Select Office</option>
                        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($office_qry)) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['officeId']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['officeName']; ?> </option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </select>
                        </div> 


<div class="clientAddPosi" id="clientAddPosi">
          <label for="formGroupExampleInput"> Position Title </label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filterPosi" placeholder="Filter Positions" name="filterPosi" style=" transition: ease 0.4s;">
                      <select class="form-control" id="posi-dropdown" name="posi-dropdown" style="transition: ease 0.4s !important;" multiple="multiple">
                    </select>
                <hr>
                </div>
        </div>

<script>
 $('#office-dd').on('change', function() {
        var officeId = this.value;
        // console.log(country_id);
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Module - Client/fetch-position.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                officeData: officeId
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#posi-dropdown').html(result);
                $('#posiDDEarn').html(result);
                $('#poSI').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The #posi-dropdown, #posiDDEarn are all working fine since they are hardcoded in the other file (clientEarningsInsert.php) but when adding the select which is #poSI, it's not working

**clientEarningsInsert.php**

```
<div class="clientAddWage" id="clientAddWage">
 <label for="formGroupExampleInput"> Position Title </label>
        <div class="form-group" style="transition: ease 0.4s !important; margin-bottom: 23px;">
            <select class="form-control" name="posiDDEarn" id="posiDDEarn" onchange="getId(this.value)">
            <option value=""></option>
             </select>
        </div>  
</div>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="width: 100% !important; margin-top: 6% !important" onclick="clientAddWage()" id="AddPosition"> Add Earning </button>
 
<script>
 function clientAddWage() {
      $("#clientAddWage").append(   
        `<div id="newWage"> <label for="formGroupExampleInput"> Position Title </label>
        <div class="form-group" style="transition: ease 0.4s !important; margin-bottom: 23px;">
           <select class="form-control" name="poSI" id="poSI" onchange="getId(this.value)">
            <option value=""></option>
             </select> 
 );
      wageIndex++;
    }
</script>
```

**Output**
[OUTPUT/THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ouh.png)

I'm really sorry if the code is not clean/written well, I'm still a beginner and looking for ways to improve. Any help regarding this would be of great help to me. Thank you!

Comment: You problem description is quite incomprehensible. `$("#clientAddWage").append( ` - where is the element with the ID `clientAddWage`, that you want to append something to here? I don't see such an element anywhere in your code.

Comment: also you appear to have some JavaScript code outside a `<script>` block, unless you've just formatted your example badly - it's unclear. It's also unclear _what_ precisely isn't "working", or what the definition of "working" is in this case. What exactly were you expecting to happen, and when? And what happens instead?

Comment: Hello. I apologize for the vagueness. I copy pasted the code I thought was necessary so some was left out.  I updated the it now. I also added on the end the output/the problem I was having. Thank you!

Comment: So...which bit isn't working then, it's still not clear? Is the problem with the `clientAddWage()` function? Or the AJAX code, or what? The picture is sort-of useful, but remember we don't know what you're expecting the application to do, so it's not immediately obvious what you consider the problem to be with that screenshot.

Comment: Yes, so the part that wasn't working was when I append/add another Position Title, it doesn't get populated unlike the first two that were hard coded. I'm also torn where the problem was but I suspect it's the AJAX code, is it possible that it can't populate appended elements? Or there's something wrong on my code?

Comment: Well the only code I can see which would populate it is `$('#poSI').html(result);`...and that only runs when the office-dd selection is changed by the user. It won't trigger just because the "Add" button was pressed. So is there some other code you were imagining would populate it at that time?

Comment: Right. That part doesn't get populated. That's exactly the problem I'm having. The office-dd, when changed is working for the first two as seen on the image but when it's the appended elements, there are no options appearing.

Comment: I just made a minimal demo, with a spoof endpoint: https://jsfiddle.net/gm6vadj9/. Initially I couldn't reproduce the problem - if you add a position and then change the office, it populates it correctly. But if you add _two_ or more positions and change the office, it only populates the first one. Why? Well you keep adding elements with the same ID "poSI"...but it's an **ID**. What is the important thing about an ID? Of course, as I'm sure you know, it must _uniquely identify_ something. So if you create multiple elements with the same ID, clearly it breaks that simple rule.

Comment: So when you then execute `$('#poSI').html(result);`, Javascript will only recognise the first element it finds with that ID. The others are rule-breakers, so they're ignored. The solution? Use a class instead as your selector: https://jsfiddle.net/gm6vadj9/1/

Comment: Oh so that's what the problem was. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I wrote it up as an answer below so you can accept / upvote it. It's totally logical once you realise what's happening :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add two or more positions and change the office, it only populates the first one. Why? Well you keep adding elements with the same ID "poSI"...but it's an **ID**. What is the important thing about an ID? Of course, as I'm sure you know, it must uniquely identify something. So if you create multiple elements with the same ID, clearly it breaks that simple rule.

So when you then execute `$('#poSI').html(result);` Javascript will only recognise the first element it finds with that ID. The others are rule-breakers, so they're ignored. The solution? Use a class instead as your selector:

```
<select class="form-control poSI" name="poSI" onchange="getId(this.value)">
```

and

```
$('.poSI').html(result);
```